# Twilio Programmable Chat without invitations

Tags: twilio, chat, twilio-programmable-chat

I've been developing a chat feature for our Android and iOS apps using the Twilio Programmable Chat, but I cannot find the option to create and add a person to the new channel, without having the other user to accept the invitation first.

Is there an easy way to just create and automatically accept the invitation, like WhatsApp?

Answer (score 3):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Invitations are a user level way of bringing other users into a channel, which is why they are exposed in the SDK.

If you just want to add a member to a channel without the invitation, you can do so via the [REST API Members resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/rest/members#add-a-member-to-a-channel). There is no need to accept an invitation, the member is created straight away.

Comment: Hi @philansh ..  Need some help here. I am doing what you suggested but can the client in front-end SDK listen to the events happening in the API. Like I added a user as a member to a private channel using rest api, but it doesn't fire the event  (memberAdded) in my js.

Comment: @tsikka as far as I know, the SDK should get events for things like that. If you're not, then I'd recommend asking a new question here on SO or getting in touch with [Twilio Support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact).